# Accessing a object array, giving result as "undefined"

Tags: jquery, loops, object

I have a object to loop. before i loop the object i decide to store the values in the separate variables, to do so i use the object notation to get the value.. i am getting undefined for "option" and "rows" - what is wrong on these both to access?

or any one suggest me the correct way to access those nodes.

here is my object :

```
var ob = {
   "DashBoard":[

    {"title":"DashBoard"},
    {"widget":[{"slide":"To do"},{"slide":"Teamspace"},{"slide":"Recent Activity"}]},
    {"activity":[
        {"option":[{"show":"Volvo"},{"show":"Benz"},{"show":"Honda"}]},
        {"rows":[

            {"title":"Advert1", "text":"sample text1", "date":"22-06-2013"},
            {"title":"Advert2", "text":"sample text2", "date":"22-06-2014"},
            {"title":"Advert3", "text":"sample text3", "date":"22-06-2015"},
            {"title":"Advert4", "text":"sample text4", "date":"22-06-2016"},
            {"title":"Advert5", "text":"sample text5", "date":"22-06-2017"}


        ]}
    ]}

   ]
} 


var title =  ob.DashBoard[0], widget= ob.DashBoard[1], option = ob.DashBoard[2]["option"], rows = ob.DashBoard[2]["rows"];

console.log(option); //undefined
console.log(rows); //undefined
```

i am getting the result as undefined on both cases...

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6933p/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read  `ob.DashBoard[2].activity[0]["option"]   and ob.DashBoard[2].activity[1]["option"].`

You will be able to read your json

Comment: works fine. But while I access the "console.log(widget.length);" - gives "undefined" - instead of 3

Comment: Use console.log(ob.DashBoard[2].widget.length)

Answer (score 1):

Use below and it should work.

```
ob.DashBoard[2].activity[0]["option"]
ob.DashBoard[2].activity[1]["option"]
```